# Hazelcast as a Windows Service

Tags: windows, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast as a Server/Client configuration and would like to know if it is possible to set up Hazelcast as a Windows Service without a 3rd party tool or without having to write more code; in other words is it possible to have the start and stop batch files used directly by the Windows Services? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to set it up as a Windows service without additional tooling, as it is a Java process and those always need the Java Service Wrapper tool (which I think is what you're thinking about to use).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply noctarius. I will go that direction then!